# OpenOfficeOrg Calc: enter data into all selected cells?

Tags: editing, openoffice-calc, cells

I want to enter the same data (e.g. "superuser") into multiple cells in OpenOffice.Org Calc (version 3.3.0). In order to do so, I select all the cells I want the data to be entered in. However, only the cell selected last (i.e. when releasing the LMB for group selection) gets the value entered subsequently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the cells, type the data and then press `enter` while keeping the `alt` key pressed.

Works on my system (Mac, OO 3.2), maybe the modifier key is different on different systems. In Excel on Windows the modifier key is `ctrl`.

Comment: ALT+ENTER works on 3.3.0 Win7 32 bit.

Comment: What about when you want to paste into multiple cells? `ctrl` or `alt` don't seem to help (Ubuntu). I would have sworn it used to Just Work (tm) with `ctrl-v`.